# FB.ui for both web and Mobile phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, facebook

I am making a html5 responsive web page that have a facebook sharing functionnality.

I already made this javascript code for FB.ui:

```
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({appId: 'appid', status: true, cookie: true,
                xfbml: true});
        };
        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fb-share-button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                FB.ui(
                        {
                            method: 'feed',
                            name: 'title',
                            link: ' http://linkToShare.com',
                            picture: 'http://helloImage.png',
                            caption: 'Caption Best',
                            description: 'Desc',
                            message: '',
                            display: 'touch'
                        });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want that the attribute "display" attribute get the value 'touch' if it is a mobile phone browser and get 'dialog' value if it is desktop browser.

I tried to put it always 'dialog' but it has strange showing issues on Firefox on Android.

Thank you;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tests around desktop and mobile devices browsers, the moste suitable paramter for displaying th FB.ui is

```
display: 'iframe'
```

Tested and working 100%